# Subsetting a function variable within another variable

Tags: r, function

I have the following function that performs a step-wise linear regression, and it works well with numerical and integer values, although, when I have factors as independent variables, I get the following error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(d, , names(resul0)) : undefined columns selected

The layout of the function:

```
stepfor(bird$Richness, data.frame(GARDENSIZE, Site, season), alfa = 0.2)
```

I have figured out a way that splits the `factors` into columns and assigns them respective values following the comments, given by this:

```
   x <- function(x) {x %>% 
            select(where(negate(is.numeric))) %>% 
            map_dfc(~ model.matrix(~ .x -1) %>% 
                        as_tibble) %>% 
            rename_all(~ str_remove(., "\\.x")) 
}
```

Though, I'm not sure how I can include it into the function below, so that x can be `implemented` with the function below by calling it `stepfor` likeso:

```
stepfor(bird$Richness, data.frame(x(bird)), alfa = 0.2)
```

I just want to know how to include the function `x` within the function below to have it work like above. And if there aren't any factors in the data, then set the function as `FALSE` so it doesn't return an error like `x is missing`.

Here is my function:

```
stepfor<-function (y = y, d = d, alfa = 0.05)
{
    pval <- NULL
    design <- NULL
    j = 1
    resul0 <- summary(lm(y ~ ., data = d))$coefficients[, 4]
    d <- as.data.frame(d[, names(resul0)][-1])
    for (i in 1:ncol(d)) {
        sub <- cbind(design, d[, i])
        sub <- as.data.frame(sub)
        lm2 <- lm(y ~ ., data = sub)
        result <- summary(lm2)
        pval[i] <- result$coefficients[, 4][j + 1]
    }
    min <- min(pval)
    while (min < alfa) {
        b <- pval == min
        c <- c(1:length(pval))
        pos <- c[b]
        pos <- pos[!is.na(pos)][1]
        design <- cbind(design, d[, pos])
        design <- as.data.frame(design)
        colnames(design)[j] <- colnames(d)[pos]
        j = j + 1
        d <- as.data.frame(d[, -pos])
        pval <- NULL
        if (ncol(d) != 0) {
            for (i in 1:ncol(d)) {
                sub <- cbind(design, d[, i])
                sub <- as.data.frame(sub)
                lm2 <- lm(y ~ ., data = sub)
                result <- summary(lm2)
                pval[i] <- result$coefficients[, 4][j + 1]
            }
            min <- min(pval, na.rm = TRUE)
        }
        else min <- 1
    }
    if (is.null(design)) {
        lm1 <- lm(y ~ 1)
    }
    else {
        lm1 <- lm(y ~ ., data = design)
    }
    return(lm1)
}
```

Reproducible code:

```
bird<- structure(list(season = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Summer", 
"Winter"), class = "factor"), Richness = c(20L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
11L, 15L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 18L, 30L, 30L, 17L, 
25L, 32L, 32L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 18L, 25L, 24L, 15L, 18L, 23L, 22L, 
25L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 17L, 22L, 7L, 15L, 16L, 20L, 24L, 21L, 22L, 
39L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 26L, 25L, 20L), GARDEN_SIZE = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("L", "M", "S"), class = "factor"), Site = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("R", "S", "U"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I now believe the problem is here ```d <- as.data.frame(d[, names(resul0)][-1])``` because the dataframe is now converting variables into several columns, it's all under a single column so the following code in the ```for-loop``` messes up when multiple columns like factors are used. I have tried ```d <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(d[, names(resul0)[-1]])))```, though the same error happens

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is with `data.frame`, because `debug` shows that `undefined columns` are given when NA's are present. I presume these NA's are introduced during the linear model.

Comment: I think if you create a function that can recode each unique factors within a column, reshape it into a wide format, assign 1 to the value of that factor where it appeared and 0 elsewhere. Repeat this with all other factors, then this should also work with factors. You previous idea won't work as it doesn't take into effect that factors are aligned into a single column, hence, how would you reshape them? So, I presume you start with my initial idea first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```r
stepfor<-function (y = y, d = d, alfa = 0.05)
{

    # split the incoming data to give non-numeric the factor treatment:
    x1 <- d %>% select(where(negate(is.numeric))) %>%
        map_dfc(~ model.matrix(~ .x -1) %>%
                    as_tibble) %>%
        rename_all(~ str_remove(., "\\.x"))
    x2 <- d %>% select(where(is.numeric))

    d <- cbind( x1, x2 )

    pval <- NULL
    design <- NULL
    j = 1
    resul0 <- summary(lm(y ~ ., data = d))$coefficients[, 4][-1]
    d <- as.data.frame(d[, names(resul0)])
 
    # rest of function body as is

}
```

eg. move the `[-1]` from the 5th line to the 4th to remove the intercept term earlier. The reamining coefficients shouldnow match the ones you have in your data.frame and `names(resul0)` should all exist in your data.frame

There is a problem with your approach to tackle this. You do:

d <- as.data.frame( d[, *names(resul0)* ] [-1] )

This code tries to look up all of the *names(resul0)* inside the *d* data.frame. This includes the intercept term, and this therefore fails. (And at this point its too late to remove the intercept *afterwards* as the damage has already been done)

You need to remove the intercept before looking up the names inside *d*. Then the name-error won't happen.

The body of the x function can be inserted in there, quite straight forward.

Comment: You're right about the factors only getting a single coefficient. I thought that replacing line 11 with `pval[i] <- result$coefficients[, 4][1:length(result$coefficients[,4])]` would fix it, along with line 30 with the same code. Though the same error. Perhaps you have an idea around this?

Comment: I have tried this, though this is actually achieved in the line after: ```d <- as.data.frame(d[, names(resul0)][-1])```. The line after also concatenates it into a single column, so I've also changed it to split the names into individual columns. However, it seems the issue arrives when performing the function: ```stepfor(bird$Richness, data.frame(bird$GARDEN_SIZE, bird$Site), alfa = 0.2)``` where the `data.frame` function, is actually what causes the disruption to the code.

Comment: It as @Lime mentions, the dataframe when it has factors, they're on a single column, and my following function doesn't take this into account when the remaining coefficients are displayed (I assume). I've managed to develop a function that splits the factors within a dataframe, however, I'm having difficulties implementing this into the step-wise function.

Comment: I added an explanation to this now. The code, as it were, looks up the names of your coefficients inside the data frame first. Then removes the interfcept. This fails as the intercept isn't there to be look up. It needs to be removed before it is looked up.

Comment: I thought this was the problem before, until I replicated the code using a linear model, then I found out that `names(resul0)` are the factor within the column that represent `Factors`, hence these are not actual column names in the `data.frame`, which explains why the output: ```undefined columns selected```. This is why I proposed on how to include the code above, becaseu this splits the facors into useable columns, where these can be used with `names(resul0)`, however, it works when using the function separately, though I'm looking for a way to include it in the bigger function.

Comment: I ran your code successfully with that one change I mentioned in my answer. Now `stepfor( bird$Richness, x(bird), alfa = 0.2 )` produces an output. Is it not correct?

Comment: You haven't expressed what your criteria is in your stepwise linear regression, though your function body likely does what it should. Do you mean to include variables only when they contribute significantly to model performance? Or when the variables themselves get a p-value < 0.05 by some test? And if so, may I repeat that perhaps an anova is better suited? Since that can flag a variable as significant regardless of which factor level contributes to it.

Comment: Yes, it does work, no doubt. Though, the question is how to include the function `x` within the `stepfor()` function, such that `bird$Richness, x(bird), alfa = 0.2 )` can work. As opposed to having the two functions separately.

Comment: just stuff the code in there, see new code proposal